# Google Cloud Platform: Logging in to GCP from commandline

Tags: gcloud

I was sure it will be simple but couldn't find any documentation or resolution.
I'm trying to write a script using gcloud to perform some operations in my GCP instances.

Is there anyway to login/authenticate using gcloud via command line only?

Thanks

Answer (score 58):

You have a couple of options here (depending on what exactly you're trying to do).

The first option is to log in using the `--no-launch-browser` option. This still requires interaction from a human user, but doesn't require a browser on the machine you're using:

```
> gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser
Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&prompt=select_account&response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute&access_type=offline


Enter verification code: *********************************************
Saved Application Default Credentials.

You are now logged in as [user@example.com].
Your current project is [None].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

The non-interactive option involves [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). The linked documentation explains them better than I can, but the short version of what you need to do is as follows:

1. Create a service account in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com). Make sure it has the appropriate "scopes" (these are permissions that determine what this service account can do. Download the corresponding JSON key file.
2. Run `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <path to key file>`.

*Note that Google Compute Engine VMs come with a slightly-different service account; the difference is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#general).*

Comment: this to date is still the best option, even behind a company VPN.
The new option `--no-browser` unfortunately doesn't work and `--no-launch-browser` will be deprecated by end of April 2022