# gcloud auth login --remote-bootstrap error. gcloud login difficulty for google vm after they change the login flow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Before gcloud login with google account (not service account). It used to be straight forward. On the vm console, type in

gcloud auth login

then you have [![enter image description here][1]][1]

You enter the link in the brower on your PC and login

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

But now the problem is when you enter gcloud auth login, you have the gcloud auth login --remote-bootstrap

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

But when you run in your PC, it redirect/turns the browser to no sure where it is

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

and then you have an error on the browser

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

any idea how to login gcloud now from the vm not using service account? Thanks

Comment: Please don't paste images into questions. The URL you include does include a valid `scope` parameter. Since this is a Google error. I encourage you to file an issue on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) specifically under the [Cloud CLI](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102). There are [other issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=gcloud%20auth%20login%20--remote-bootstrap) with the implementation of this functionality.

Comment: Delete images as per advised. Checked the provided link but looks like it is not an error issue for them, just express about the user experience downgrade. Will ask on that side

Comment: @Alex Please raise a ticket with [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).

Comment: --no-launch-browser worked for me from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873177/google-cloud-platform-logging-in-to-gcp-from-commandline